# is it possible in ios to programatically call a person and then let him/her hear a pre-recorded voice/audio?

Tags: ios

I want to know if it is possible using public API's to call a person programatically and then as soon as she picks up the phone, let her hear a pre-recorded voice message/audio?

Before I get comments like why I want to do that, or its a bad user experience, I just want to clarify that the question is more on the technical front than implementational so please do let me know if you have any pointers.

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know for calling someone is by using  `openURL` on `UIApplication` using the  `tel:` scheme.

This launches the Call application, which takes the focus and you cannot play your own message with it.

You probably already know about the `openURL` but I thought I would mention it just in case, even if it does not help you playing a prerecorded message.